# (T)SQL case statement (not expression)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, switch-statement, case

Is there any alternative way to do multiple statements based on conditions:
if(expr1) then select this else if(expr2) then select that

...the case would serve this purpose nice, if it weren't limited to expressions.
I'm using sql server

Code until now:

```
if(@code=57) begin (lots of complex statements) end
if(@code=58) begin (lots of other complex statements) end
if(@code=59) begin (lots of other complex statements) end
if(@code=60) begin (lots of other complex statements) end
```

I can't use a case, because it's an expression and it returns values, it cannot run statements.

Comment: CASE may work fine, what is your problem? Give us specific details, tables, data etc. and show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I think you need to use UNION, not case.

Comment: Given the description so far how can you even tell that a UNION may be the solution?

Comment: Give us an example.

Comment: I see no reason yet why a case should not do the job here

Comment: there is no `switch` construct in T-SQL, and you are correct about case - it can't be used as a flow control element. I don't think T-SQL provides a different syntax to what you already have.

Comment: Thanks, Zohar, for understanding and answering.

Answer (score 0):

IF is a procedural statement, that is to say it directs the flow of statements in a multi-statement batch or procedure. CASE cannot do this. Though it may look like a procedural statement, CASE is actually a function; it returns different values based on the input. CASE does not redirect the control of program flow. CASE can invoke subqueries; this might be unwise from a performance perspective, but even at that the subqueries could only return a single value.